# Animating position across row cells in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I have a `Row` Widget that holds a child Widget in one of its cells (the others hold a `Spacer()`). Depending on the state, the cell which holds the child changes, resulting in a position change of the child Widget. I want to animate this motion to make it smooth. Is there a way of doing so with the standard animation Widgets (something like `AnimatedPositioned`, which won't work in this case)?

Comment: Don't know if i got the idea, but I believe you can use a Stack with two rows in the same position using a Positioned. 
The first row has all the cells filled with spaces and is only to represent the cells of the row. The second row, has another Stack and an AnimatedPositioned that holds the Widget. When the state changes you move the widget position inside the second row. The effect will be like the Widget is moving across the cells like you expect if i understood.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need even two rows. Just the first row, and an AnimatedPositioned with the Widget.

Comment: This is not what I meant. I want to use Row to position the widget, not to use Position to directly put the child widget in a specific locaion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AnimatedPositioned if you insert a Stack inside your row.
Otherwise, you can use an `AnimatedBuilder` with `Transform.translate` and animate the `Offset` on the axis X of your widget. Bellow there's a complete example, that you can run at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/) to see the result. Hope it helps.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyAnimation()));

}

class MyAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAnimationState createState() => _MyAnimationState();
}

class _MyAnimationState extends State<MyAnimation> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> animation;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
  animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 300.0).animate(_controller);
  _controller.forward();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
    body: AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[ 
            Transform.translate(
            child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.black),
            offset: Offset(animation.value, 0),
          ),
          Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.transparent),
          Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.transparent),]
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: Small bug; you'll need to add `late` to the `_controller` and `animation` variables if you want to declare and initialize them like this.

Answer (score 0):

Same [concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76828925/21506239) but using [TweenSequence](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html), you need to customize the sample to achieve similar goal.