# Flutter Animation Design

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How can I achieve similar animation in Flutter ? Tried different animation with Animated position. It seems to be failing.

https://giphy.com/gifs/XJ1awq5Wr83uJFkLup

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "seems to be failing"? Maybe provide some code that you've tried and the error that it produces.

Comment: have you checked this package? -> flutter_animate by gSkinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](https://gist.github.com/Ric17101/35a7d64ec0d3a2e251abad3fa85b3594) example custom made swap animation using [TweenSequence](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html)

```
final Animation<double> animation = TweenSequence<double>(
 <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: Tween<double>(begin: 5.0, end: 10.0)
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease)),
    weight: 40.0,
  ),
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: ConstantTween<double>(10.0),
    weight: 20.0,
  ),
 ],
).animate(myAnimationController);
```

Though, customization may take some effort for you to apply this on more than 2 items, i believe this simple example can take you to what you wanted to achieve based on your animation design.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 different ways to implement this.

The easy path is to define a logic class for the graphic, save the bar's relative position, and create logic for animating the switch between the position of 2 bars at the time. (Flutter already has some types of animation predefined for these situations.

Then the whole animation can be controlled by a sequence of timed events, that call the switch position for the 2 elements, the logic for the next pick, and the end conditions of the animation.

The hard path is for you to track all of those elements by yourself, disregarding every Flutter widget, and use the Canvas and a Painter to make everything manually, which might not be as hard as it might seem but still makes you do some work.